# How to disable all form fields except buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am new to web designing using PHP and java script.

I have "Clear", "View", "Edit", "Save" buttons in my form in addition to 50 input fields.

On giving the key fields value and clicking "View" I want to retrieve that record from DB and display it and make all fields "Display only". On clicking "Edit", all fields can be made Editable.

Kindly help me with suggestions for this.

I used the below function on the Onclick event of the "View" button

```
 function DisableFields()
        {
        var form = document.getElementById(form id);
        var elements = form.elements;
        for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (elements[i].type != 'submit') {
                elements[i].disabled  = true;
            }
        }
        }
```

What is happening is, the fields are getting non editable and immediately changes back to Editable fields. If I disable all the buttons as well, then it is fully being disabled.

Comment: jquery is the newbie friendly approach

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code you posted would cause the behavior you describe.

My best guess is that you have some other code which is submitting the form by pragmatically clicking one of the submit buttons, causing the page to reload at which point the inputs are not disabled.

By disabling the submit buttons you'd be preventing this from happening.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I have a similar "onclick" function to enable all fields in the "Edit" button. If I disable that button too, all fields are disabled. Else all fields are enabled.